# Why can i not send a string but only a number to a member function?

Tags: php

Im making my own function to search for the total number of something. but it is not working propperly. function getNumberOfCounts gets the $fromIndex but not the searchWord

```
public function getNumberOfCounts( $searchWord, $fromIndex )
{       
    $index = $fromIndex;
    $counter = 0;

    while( $index <= $endPos )
    {
        $index++;

        $pos = strpos( $this->text, $searchWord, ($index+1) );

        if( $pos > $index )
        {
            $counter++;

            $index = $pos;
        }
        else
            break;

    }

    return $counter;
}

public function searchDemo()
{
    $startPos = 11; // ex

    echo "<br /> count= " . $this->getNumberOfCounts( "Lorem", $startPos );
}
```

They are both part of the same class ofc.

**EDIT: i know there is some missing info, but if I try to print $searchWord on the first line of getNumberOfCounts nothing is outputted.**

Comment: You must be omitting something critical then. It's virtually impossible for this to not pass the string. Please post an example that can be run as is which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely have less problems and better performing code when just using

- [substr_count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) — Count the number of substring occurrences

Comment: Hmm... not a bad idea. im not that familiar with the php documentation so thanks for mention it :D

Answer (score 2):

You're starting from position 11 for starters, which would be greater than the total length of "Lorem". Secondly, in your while loop, you're running while startpos < endpos. $endpos hasn't been assigned a value yet, so it's not even entering the loop.

While I'm at it, you're incrementing index at the start of the loop (probably not desired). It's usually the case the the index is incremented at the end of the loop, so you can use the index to "index into" an array without having to shift position.

Comment: read my edit... i know there is some missing information, did not need to post it all as i think its not relevant.